# Find row and set value in column google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2d array:

```
const arr = [ [ 'John Doe',
    'john@something.com',
    'Some text here',
    '' ],
  [ 'Steven Smith',
    'steven@something.com',
    'Another irrelevant text here',
    '' ],
]
```

I want to find a row in the tab that matches the name in each array in this list and add a text value in the last column (where the '' is).

For example:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
const range = sheet.getDataRange()
const data = range.getValues()
const people = data.slice(1)
```

if a name in `arr` is found in `people`, add the text 'Found' in the last column in `people` for that name.

`people` looks like this:

```
[ [ 'John Doe',
    'john@something.com',
    'Some text here',
    '' ] ]
```

I was able to find the match using this:

```
const peopleTarget = arr.map(person => people.find(el => el[0] === person[0]))
```

However, I need the **row number** to be able to set a value.
I know I need the `getRange` to be able to use `setValue` but I'm having difficulty grabbing the row number based on matching value between two arrays.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a set of names from `arr`,  iterate over `data`  and modify them in-place. Then `setValues` the modified array.

```
const arr = [
    ['John Doe', 'john@something.com', 'Some text here', ''],
    [
      'Steven Smith',
      'steven@something.com',
      'Another irrelevant text here',
      '',
    ],
  ],
  arrSet = new Set(arr.map((el) => el[0]));
data.forEach((people) =>
  arrSet.has(people[0]) ? (people[3] = 'found') : null
);
range.setValues(data);
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about modifying data in place.

Comment: @SevenSouls Do read "Best practices": see [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)